# How can I create a colorful scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a colorful scatter plot and I have seen a usage of

> `plt.scatter(x, y, c = 'rby')`

But when I use it ,it cant work.

> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not 'rby'

so **how can I create a colorful scatter plot by matplotlib**

Comment: What did you intend 'rby' to mean?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the `scatter` function?

Comment: red, blue, yellow

Comment: [List of named colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html). `rby` is not a valid color. If you thought this would be a sequence of red-blue-yellow, you should make it a list: `list("rby")`.

Comment: When I used this ,it told me  >ValueError: 'c' argument has 3 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 20.

Comment: What do you expect? Of course, x, y, and c should be arrays of the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want points to be scattered alternatively with red, blue and yellow color, you should provide a list of colors with the same length as your data.

```
N = len(x)
colors = (list('rby')*(1+N//3))[:N] #messy way of getting ['r', 'b', 'y', 'r',...]
plt.scatter(x, y, c = colors )
```

[image: result]